# Can't get port forwarding to work on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, port-forwarding

I'm using my server as NAT/router, which works well. But now I'm trying to forward port 3478, which I can't get to work.

eth0 = public interface
eth1 = private network

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding
1
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth1/forwarding
1
```

Then to forward port 3478 to 10.0.0.7, I read somewhere that I should run

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 3478 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.7:3478
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.0.0.7 --dport 3478 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

I also ran

```
ufw allow 3478
```

But testing port 3478 with http://www.canyouseeme.org/ doesn't work. Any idea what I have done wrong?

Comment: Here's a few methods of port forwarding http://serverfault.com/questions/401842/forward-localhost-memcached-server-on-port-12111-to-domain-com-memcached-server

Comment: Does the machine `10.0.0.7` also have a proper Netfilter `MASQUERADING` or `SNAT` rule?

Comment: @AlexanderJanssen No idea, it's a Win 7 box

Comment: @Znarkus in mean in your Ubuntu firewall. Check the OUTPUT chain of the NAT table.

Comment: @AlexanderJanssen `iptables -L OUTPUT -t nat` looks empty.

Comment: @Znarkus Try a `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 3478 -s 10.0.0.7 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` - this enables SNAT for this very one IP-address.

Answer (score 1):

I use port forwarding (and working) on Ubuntu server with:

```
#NAT:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3478 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.7

#FORWARD:
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth0 -d 10.0.0.7 --dport 3478 -j ACCEPT
```